# reason ceiling fan/light will work, stop working for month, start working again with no repair made

Tags: ceiling-fan, light

I live in a mobile home.  Bedroom ceiling fan/light worked fine.  Next day no power.  Tried switch weeks later.  Fixture worked with no repairs.  Is it safe to use?  If I just leave the switch off will everything be safe.  Cannot really afford repairs at this time.

Comment: Possibly a loose connection.  Those are NOT safe.  I'd work hard to confirm / track it down.

Answer (score -1):

Might/might not be the switch. I'd pull the switch out and ensure the wires are all secure and look fine. Otherwise, it sounds like a short and just toggling the switch might disrupt it.

Comment: A short would trip the breaker, a loose connection is an open and arcing will happen and this can cause fires. I would be checking at the switch then fan for loose connections, signs of arcing or back stabs if ok check at the fan.

Comment: Micah if a short dosenot trip the breaker you probably have a stab lock panel made by FPE. Other than that a short will trip the breaker as by definition a 0 ohm load or a short draws infinant current, I have seen shorts on #10 wire trip 800 amp breakers.

Comment: Look at the curves a dead short is supposed to trip in just a few cycles, I test breakers as part of my job and use trip curves regularly. In close to 40 years as an electrician I have only found a few breakers that did not trip when shorted and every one also failed there trip curve response at 110% load so they were defective. Just because there is an answer dosenot mean that it is correct I have seen accepted answers that were wrong but it matched what the OP wanted so they accepted the answer. 99.9% of electrical failures similar to this question are caused from an open circuit.

Comment: Many people don't understand the difference or incorrectly call an open circuit a "short".  A short is a zero (or very low ohm) connection between the hot and neutral or hot and ground - a shortcut around the load - allowing a very high current.  An open circuit, often a bad connection or broken wire, is like a switch that's turned off - no current.  Sometimes such a bad connection or broken wire can make a short, causing arcing (sparks), which can start a fire.